# TO Use Cygwin within Eclipse 3.6

Tags: java, unix, jakarta-ee, cygwin

I'm working in J2EE application. We are developing application in java/j2ee. In our project we use cygwin to simulate linux os, run shell script included in application and to deploy. How to use eclipse to embed eclipse and cygwin and deloy in run/debug mode. 
Am new to this kind of stuff and confused to how to proceed further. Please suggest me how to proceed with this.

Thanks in advance.

Appreciated for guiding...

We r developing j2ee project in window env. and deploying in linux server.
so to simulate linux in windows we use cygwin.
Now we use eclipse to develop and get into cmd prompt and start cygwin and then run basic shell script to initialize variables and build the project and deploy the EAR in linux server ... 
For these two purpose i have to toggle the window and i couldn't debug the code and check for check time data.

Is there any possibility to merge cygwin with eclipse to start the server  or in run in debug mode, so that my developement process would be efficient and easy to code walk through... My enter team is following the first process which may tedious work.

Can any one suggest to work efficient with this project

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here, so would you be able to clarify a bit more? Java is still running under windows and has no knowledge of the cygwin dll's.

You should be be able to run scripts from Java by executing the shell from cygwin's bin directory.

If you want JNI, using gcc from Cygwin and ensure that the native library has access to Cygwin's DLL should be enough, though I haven't tried it.

Comment: 80% of my projects for the last 5 years are Java-based and built with Maven. We develop locally on Windows and deploy to Unix/Linux seamlessly. The only trick is environment-specific configuration which you can manage with Maven filters and profiles.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use shell scripts for your deployment process. Maven almost certainly has plugins for everything your shell scripts are currently doing, and it runs on Windows and Linux transparently.